# Symfony2 $request->query->get() returning null value

Tags: symfony-2.3

I'm new to Symfony2.I am understanding the framework.
I try to access the get parameters of my request using Symfony2.
But it is returning null when I access them like

```
$name = $request->query->get('name');
echo $name;
```

My code for controller is

```
namespace abc\myBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

 public function getnameAction()
{

    $request = $this->get('request');
    echo $request->getMethod();

    $name = $request->query->get('name');
    echo $name. "---";

}
```

my routing file is as follows:

```
abcmy_newpage:
    pattern:  /new/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: abcmyBundle:new:getname }
```

When I run the URL

```
http://dashboardsmf.iiit.ac.in/web/app_dev.php/new/India
```

I get the method name 
    "GET" 
corresponding to echo statement " echo $request->getMethod(); ".

But I get the null/"" blank value for the echo statement 
    echo $name. "---";

I dont know where I have mistaken.
Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change you action to this:

```
public function getnameAction($name) {
    echo $name;
}
```

Symfony binds parameters defined in routing file to parameter names in action method (see [Symfony book chapter on controller parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#route-parameters-as-controller-arguments) for more details).

If you want to use `$request->query` to get your parameters it should be passed like this: `http://http://dashboardsmf.iiit.ac.in/web/app_dev.php/new?name=India`.